# VBA .shapes.pastespecial fails intermittently

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I get intermittent failure with .Shapes.PasteSpecial. It works most of the times but since I use it often it makes the full report fail.

I am doing a report in Powerpoint with data from excel. 
In excel I have organised data in cells in the way it shall be presented in ppt and using slicers to select what data should the presented. 
My problem is that when running the sub routine to create the report it fails sometimes. 
For each report the routine below is called ~50 times and the error occcur ~every 3rd report attempt but not for same report area.

Error message: 
Run time error '-2147188160 (80048240)':
Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request. The specified data type in unavailable.

and points to 
`.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2`

Is this a timing issue with VBA or something else?

I have tried other ways to doe the paste but this does not work for me (copying cells and pasting into ppt as image).

```
Public Function CopyRngAndPasteToPowerpoint(rng As Range, activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide, stepInLadder As Integer) As Integer
    'Copy Excel Range
        rng.Copy

    'calculate position based on step in ladder
    Dim leftPosition, topPosition, offsetX, offsetY As Integer
    offsetX = 35
    offsetY = 60
    leftPosition = 75 + (offsetX * stepInLadder)
    topPosition = 350 - (offsetY * stepInLadder)

    'Paste to PowerPoint and position
        With activeSlide
            .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
            With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Left = leftPosition
                .Top = topPosition
                .ScaleHeight 0.28, msoFalse
            End With
        End With

    CopyRngAndPasteToPowerpoint = 1

End Function
```

Comment: Clipboard operations in Office VBA often have timing problems. There are many answers to this issue, search for VBA Sleep, Wait and DoEvents as solutions.

Comment: Many thanks @JohnKorchok! Worked perfectly just adding a short wait before pastespecial. :-)